# How to quickly find the rectangle containing it for each point in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, geospatial

I have a dataframe called `grid_df`, which contains many rectangles coordinate. And another dataframe called `trajectory_df`, which contains many point coordinate.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

sqlContext = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("test").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
data = [(0,0,0,5,5),(1,0,3,5,8)]
grid_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, schema=['grid_id','lat_min','lng_min','lat_max','lng_max'])

data = [(0,1,1,),(1,2,2),(2, 4, 3),(3, 7, 4)]
trajectory_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, schema=['point_id','lng','lat'])
```

The data shows:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|grid_id|lat_min|lng_min|lat_max|lng_max|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|      0|      0|      0|      5|      5|
|      1|      0|      3|      5|      8|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+

+--------+---+---+
|point_id|lng|lat|
+--------+---+---+
|       0|  1|  1|
|       1|  2|  2|
|       2|  4|  3|
|       3|  7|  4|
+--------+---+---+
```

I want to find the rectangle containing it for each coordinate point. I expect the output to be as follows. `new_list` represents the rectangle id `grid_id` that contains the point.

```
+--------+---+---+--------+
|point_id|lng|lat|new_list|
+--------+---+---+--------+
|       0|  1|  1|     [0]|
|       1|  2|  2|     [0]|
|       2|  4|  3|  [0, 1]|
|       3|  7|  4|     [1]|
+--------+---+---+--------+
```

There are thousands of records in `grid_df` and hundreds of millions in `trajectory_df` in my actual data. I've Google a lot of information, like [GIS with pySpark : A not-so-easy journey](https://gist.github.com/4rzael/bbd543af0cb2ee087771f42c5aefdad7#gistcomment-2882649) and [PySparkGeoAnalysis](https://ncar.github.io/PySpark4Climate/tutorials/pyspark-geo-analysis/coastal-marine-zones/). But didn't find a solution for me because these methods either apply a rectangle or don't support pyspark.

I hope the solution is quick enough. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using `join` could be a costly operation, as you have mentioned that `trajectory_df` has lot of points. However, the computational speed can be blamed on the cluster size in spark.

```
#Logic here is lat should be between lat_min and lat_max. Similar condition for lng too.
>>> grid_df.join(trajectory_df,((trajectory_df.lat>=grid_df.lat_min) & (trajectory_df.lat<=grid_df.lat_max) & (trajectory_df.lng>=grid_df.lng_min) & (trajectory_df.lng<=grid_df.lng_max))).groupBy(trajectory_df.point_id).agg(F.collect_list("grid_id").alias("grid_id")).show()
+--------+-------+
|point_id|grid_id|
+--------+-------+
|       0|    [0]|
|       1|    [0]|
|       3|    [1]|
|       2| [0, 1]|
+--------+-------+
```

Try it!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I still want to find a more effective solution. Of course I voted for you.